# In Drupal 8 views cannot add paragraph fields to exposed filter

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8, drupal-views-relationship

In Drupal 8 views exposed filter I want to add paragraph fields of a content type but they are not showing up when I try to add them. I tried adding a relationship entity reference to the field in Views 'Advanced > Relationships' still I am not able to add the fields in exposed filter.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have paragraph type `choices` and a list (text) field `field_system` and you have added this paragraph type as `field_choices` to `page` content type.

In your view you should add a relationship `Paragraph referenced from field_choices`

[image]

and then the field system would be available to be used as a filter field

[image]